# MS-Excel Networkingdays formula subject to workweek

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I managed to use the following formula to calculate the net working days between two dates.The problem is i would like to make it possible for the user to enter what days of the week the person works in another cell and automatically update the formula. Just to make it more user friendly, and prevent the user from messing with the formula. Is there anyway to enter the string(12345) in another cell and have the formula update automatically?

Thanks in advance

```
Option Explicit
'
' This function tells you how many working days are there between 2 given dates.
' You can use this to calculate working days in countries where saturday and sunday are
' not usually holidays.
'
Function NetWorkingDays(sDateRng As Range, eDateRng As Range, workingDays As String, _
Optional HolidayRng As Range) As Long
'
' e.g. use: =NetWorkingDays($A$1,$A$2,"12356")
'           will tell you the count of mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, fridays and saturdays
 '           between the dates in $A$1 and $A$2
 '
 ' e.g. use: =NetWorkingDays($A$1,$A$2,"12356",$H$2:$H$50)
 '           will tell you the count of mondays, tuesdays, wednesdays, fridays and saturdays
 '           between the dates in $A$1 and $A$2, excluding any holidays (listed as dates) in
 '           the range $H$2:$H$50
 '
 ' You can also count the number of individual days between dates:
 '          =NetWorkingDays($A$1,$A$2,"2")
 '          will tell you the number of tuesdays between those two dates
 '
 Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date, Holidays() As Variant
 Dim nHolidays As Long
 Dim totalDays, startDay As Long, endDay As Long
 Dim totWeeks As Long, extraDays As Long
 Dim curWeekday As Long
 Dim i, retVal As Long
 '
 If (Not IsDate(sDateRng.Value)) Then
 sDate = 0#
 Else
 sDate = sDateRng.Value
 End If
 '
 If (Not IsDate(eDateRng.Value)) Then
 eDate = 0#
 Else
 eDate = eDateRng.Value
 End If
 '
 If (Not HolidayRng Is Nothing) Then
 nHolidays = HolidayRng.Cells.Count
 ReDim Holidays(0 To nHolidays - 1)
 Holidays = HolidayRng.Value2 ' CAREFUL - this automatically assumes dates in the range!
 Else
 nHolidays = 0
 End If
 '
 totalDays = eDate - sDate + 1
 startDay = Weekday(sDate, vbMonday)
 endDay = Weekday(eDate, vbMonday)
 '
 ' First calculate the number of whole weeks in the date span.
 ' Whole weeks are defined as all weeks that start on Monday and
 ' end on Sunday.
 '
 If (startDay = 1) Then
      If (endDay = 7) Then
          extraDays = 0
      Else
          extraDays = 7 - endDay
      End If
 Else
      If (endDay = 7) Then
          extraDays = 7 - startDay + 1
      Else
          extraDays = 7 - startDay + 1 + endDay
      End If
 End If
 totWeeks = (totalDays - extraDays) / 7
 '
 ' Now determine how many "extra" days are on either side of
 ' the whole weeks.  Include only those "extra" days that are
 ' a part of the "workingDays" string.
 '
 extraDays = 0
 If (startDay <> 1) Then
 For i = startDay To 7
    If (InStr(workingDays, CStr(i)) > 0) Then
        extraDays = extraDays + 1
    End If
 Next i
 End If
 If (endDay <> 7) Then
 For i = 1 To endDay
    If (InStr(workingDays, CStr(i)) > 0) Then
        extraDays = extraDays + 1
    End If
 Next i
 End If
 '
 retVal = totWeeks * Len(workingDays) + extraDays
 '
 ' Now subtract out the holidays if applicable to the period in question
 '
 If (nHolidays > 0) Then
 For i = LBound(Holidays) To UBound(Holidays)
    If (InStr(workingDays, Weekday(Holidays(i, 1), vbMonday)) > 0 And _
        Holidays(i, 1) >= sDate And Holidays(i, 1) <= eDate) Then
        retVal = retVal - 1
 'Debug.Print Format(Holidays(i, 1), "dd mmm, yyyy") & " was     removed: it is a " & Format(Holidays(i, 1), "dddd")
    Else
 'Debug.Print Format(Holidays(i, 1), "dd mmm, yyyy") & " was not removed: it is a " & Format(Holidays(i, 1), "dddd")
    End If
 Next i
 End If
 '
 NetWorkingDays = retVal
 End Function
```

Comment: Hi, Could this be done with a factor, i.e. 0.5 being 2.5 days a week or does it need to be like x works weds and Fridays, so mon-thu, only 1 day work for x

Comment: only one day for each day of the week 1= monday 2 = tuesday 3= Wednesday etc... i got the code from here http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/06/09/networkingdays/ from EJGUN  comments